# Call a function inside view controller from his super

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am sorry if i am not accurate in my terms. i will be glad if someone can fix me.

I have a ViewController "GeneralCard".

Based on the "GeneralCard" i have created a sibling ViewController called "BlueCard" like that:

```
@interface BlueCardViewController : GeneralViewController
```

(I did off course because i have many cards types that all inherits same properties from the "GeneralCard").

It works great but now i am trying something new -

all the cards have a **UIGestureRecognizer** that shoots function that changes the card content.
I want to try to move the **UIGestureRecognizer** to the "GeneralCard" but to make the gesture call a function that located in the specific card (BlueCardViewController etc). since the function is different in each card.

Is that possible?
And what are the correct terms for the object in this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `[self someMethod]` it will work its way up from the lowest level class (the one that init was called on) to find the method. So, as long as you have implemented someMethod in the BlueCardViewController class it will be the one called.

Comment: Thanks, that was simple. BTW i now use @selector, so i didn't get compiler warning. will i get one if i will use [self someMethod]?

Comment: You want to make sure you declare and implement someMethod in your base class as well even if that method doesn't do anything. Then you won't get compiler warnings